# Paint cell background based on the values of three columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have three columns of color data in my worksheet. They are labeled R, G and B and contain float values between 0 and 1. How do I color the background of a fourth cell in each row based on the R, G and B values?

Thanks.

This code works when you hover over a cell:

```
=HYPERLINK(SetRGB(D2,A2*255,B2*255,C2*255),"HOVER!")
```

But I would like to pre-compute the colors for every row.

Comment: You will likely need VBA - what have you tried?  Are you saying that A, B, and C columns for each row have a numeric value that you want to assign, respectively to the RGB colors?

Comment: Typically, RGB values are specified on a 0-255 scale.  How do your 0-1 values relate to that (surely you aren't talking about shades of near black)?

Comment: Just multiply the 0-1 scale by 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Range("D1").Interior.Color = RGB(Range("A1"), Range("B1"), Range("C1"))
End Sub
```

Comment: "Please try this code" sounds pretty speculative for an answer.  Also, can you add a sentence or two to explain how this works?  Will the RGB function work with values in the 0-1 range?